# Plane curves from interval I to a three dimensional space

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

I'm studying differential geometry and for the definition of curve we have said that it's the image of a fucntion $r(t)$ , $t\in I$, where $I$ is an interval of the real number. Suppose we have that $r: I -> \Bbb R^3$ .

Now what I know, is that a curve is called "plane curve" when $r(t) , \forall t \in I$, are inside a plane. If $r : I -> \Bbb R^2$, it's prety obvious that is is plane since it's codomain is the Euclidean plane. But in the case I wrote above, where we have $\Bbb R^3$, I can't understand how a curve can be plane.

Can someone explain with an example or maybe with a graph? I already looked online but I can't find anything. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For example you can choose $r(t)=t(1,1,0)$ that it is a line that lying on the plane $\Pi=\{(x,y,z): z=0\}$

In general you can associate a map $r: I\to \mathbb{R}^2$ a plane curve $r^\sim$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ in this way:

for any $t\in I$ $r^\sim (t)=(r_1(t),r_2(t),0)$

Or, for example

for any $t\in I$ $r^\sim (t)=(r_1(t),0,r_2(t))$ 
(In this case the curve lying on the plane $y=0$)

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I thought about that as well, I mean having the third coordinate as 0, but is there an example where the $z$ isn't 0?

Comment: Do you want any clarification?

Comment: I want, if there is, an example where all the coordinates are non zero. I understand that when one of them is zero, the curve is obviously restricted to a plane, either the $xy$-plane, the $xz$-plane or the $yz$ - plane. And it will stay in there. But if there are 3 non zero coordinates it means it exists in all the 3 axes and this is the Euclidean space.

Comment: The only thing I could maybe imagine is the $r(t)=t(1,1,1)$ which if I am not mistaken is a straight line in space. But are there examples of a non-straight curve?

Comment: It is simple, you can consider the curve $r(t)=(r_1(t),r_2(t),0)$ that it is on the plane xy and you can acts on it a rotation matrix that change the plane xy in other ‘non trivial’ plane. If M is the rotation matrix than $s(t)=M r(t)$ is a plane curve on the new plane

Comment: @Thomas $\left(3\cos t-\sqrt3\sin t,-3\cos t-\sqrt3\sin t,2\sqrt3\sin t\right)$ is a circle on the plane $x+y+z=0$.

Comment: Ok thank you guys for tha answers. Ill try to think it more by myself because I think it's something I must understand on my own